# f# pattern matching with types

Tags: f#, types, pattern-matching

I'm trying to recursively print out all an objects properties and sub-type properties etc.  My object model is as follows...

```
type suggestedFooWidget = {
    value: float ; 
    hasIncreasedSinceLastPeriod: bool ;
}

type firmIdentifier = {
    firmId: int ;
    firmName: string ;
}
type authorIdentifier = {
    authorId: int ;
    authorName: string ;
    firm: firmIdentifier ;
}

type denormalizedSuggestedFooWidgets = {
    id: int ; 
    ticker: string ;
    direction: string ;
    author: authorIdentifier ;
    totalAbsoluteWidget: suggestedFooWidget ;
    totalSectorWidget: suggestedFooWidget ;
    totalExchangeWidget: suggestedFooWidget ;
    todaysAbsoluteWidget: suggestedFooWidget ;
    msdAbsoluteWidget: suggestedFooWidget ;
    msdSectorWidget: suggestedFooWidget ;
    msdExchangeWidget: suggestedFooWidget ;
}
```

And my recursion is based on the following pattern matching...

```
let rec printObj (o : obj) (sb : StringBuilder) (depth : int) 
    let props = o.GetType().GetProperties()
    let enumer = props.GetEnumerator()
    while enumer.MoveNext() do
        let currObj = (enumer.Current : obj)
        ignore <|
             match currObj with
             | :? string as s -> sb.Append(s.ToString())
             | :? bool as c -> sb.Append(c.ToString())
             | :? int as i -> sb.Append(i.ToString())
             | :? float as i -> sb.Append(i.ToString())
             | _ ->  printObj currObj sb (depth + 1)
    sb
```

In the debugger I see that currObj is of type string, int, float, etc but it always jumps to the defualt case at the bottom.  Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is how I got it to work...

```
 let getMethod = prop.GetGetMethod()
 let value = getMethod.Invoke(o, Array.empty)
     ignore <|
         match value with
         | :? float as f -> sb.Append(f.ToString() + ", ") |> ignore
                            ...
```

Answer (score 19):

As others has pointed out, you need to invoke the `GetValue` member to get the value of the property - the iteration that you implemented iterates over `PropertyInfo` objects, which are "descriptors of the property" - not actual values. However, I don't quite understand why are you using `GetEnumerator` and `while` loop explicitly when the same thing can be written using `for` loop.

Also, you don't need to ignore the value returned by the `sb.Append` call - you can simply return it as the overall result (because it is *the* `StringBuilder`). This will actually make the code more efficient (because it enables tail-call optimizataion). As a last point, you don't need `ToString` in `sb.Append(..)`, because the `Append` method is overloaded and works for all standard types.

So after a few simplification, you can get something like this (it's not really using the `depth` parameter, but I guess you want to use it for something later on):

```
let rec printObj (o : obj) (sb : StringBuilder) (depth : int) =
  let props = o.GetType().GetProperties() 
  for propInfo in props do
    let propValue = propInfo.GetValue(o, null)
    match propValue with 
    | :? string as s -> sb.Append(s) 
    | :? bool as c -> sb.Append(c) 
    | :? int as i -> sb.Append(i) 
    | :? float as i -> sb.Append(i) 
    | _ ->  printObj currObj sb (depth + 1)
```

Comment: I've been putting |> ignore and returning ()

Answer (score 3):

In your example, `enumer.Current` is an object containing a PropertyInfo. This means that currObj is always a PropertyInfo object, and will always correspond to the last case in your match statement.

Since you're interested in the type of the *value* of the property, you'll need to call the GetValue() method of the PropertyInfo to get to the actual value of the property (as in ChaosPandion's answer).

Since an Enumerator returns its values as objects, you'll also need to cast the enum.current to a PropertyInfo before you can access GetValue.

Try replacing

```
let currObj = (enumer.Current : obj)
```

with

```
let currObj = unbox<PropertyInfo>(enumer.Current).GetValue (o, null)
```

With this change, I can get your code to work (in FSI):

```
>  let test = {authorId = 42; authorName = "Adams"; firm = {firmId = 1; firmName = "GloboCorp inc."} };;
> string <| printObj test (new StringBuilder()) 1;;
val it : string = "42Adams1GloboCorp inc."
```

Answer (score 0):

You want something like this instead.

```
let rec printObj (o : obj) (sb : StringBuilder) (depth : int) 
    let props = o.GetType().GetProperties() :> IEnumerable<PropertyInfo>
    let enumer = props.GetEnumerator()
    while enumer.MoveNext() do
        let currObj = (enumer.Current.GetValue (o, null)) :> obj
        ignore <|
             match currObj with
             | :? string as s -> sb.Append(s.ToString())
             | :? bool as c -> sb.Append(c.ToString())
             | :? int as i -> sb.Append(i.ToString())
             | :? float as i -> sb.Append(i.ToString())
             | _ ->  printObj currObj sb (depth + 1)
    sb
```

This is coming from the MSDN docs on the `Array` class:

> In the .NET Framework version 2.0, the
>   Array  class implements the
>   System.Collections.Generic.IList,
>   System.Collections.Generic.ICollection,
>   and
>   System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable
>   generic interfaces. The
>   implementations are provided to arrays
>   at run time, and therefore are not
>   visible to the documentation build
>   tools. As a result, the generic
>   interfaces do not appear in the
>   declaration syntax for the Array
>   class, and there are no reference
>   topics for interface members that are
>   accessible only by casting an array to
>   the generic interface type (explicit
>   interface implementations). The key
>   thing to be aware of when you cast an
>   array to one of these interfaces is
>   that members which add, insert, or
>   remove elements throw
>   NotSupportedException.

Comment: The compiler is telling me:
the field, constructor or member 'GetValue' is not defined

Comment: @philbrowndotcom - I think you need to do a cast.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the program is not behaving as expected?  The debugger spans are not always reliable.

Comment: The problem is that the enumer.Current.GetValue is not really the the value, it's a PropertyInfo object.  There is some abstraction here that has me confused.

Comment: So what API are you using with the GetType/GetProperties/etc?  Perhaps the docs for it explain this?