# F#: Returning values of different types from a single function

Tags: f#, functional-programming

I am trying to have a function that returns either one type or another. Is there any way in F# to encode this *without* creating a new discriminated union type and returning that discriminated union from the function?

Here is a simple example that will not compile:

```
type Json = JNumber of float 
          | JString of string 
          | JArray of seq<Json>
          | JObject of Map<string, Json>
          | JBool of bool 
          | JNull

let parseJson(jason:Json)  = match jason with
                             |JNumber num -> num
                             |JString str -> str
                             |JArray  arr -> arr |> Seq.map (fun e -> parseJson e)
                             |JObject obj -> obj |> Seq.map (fun (k,v) -> (k, parseJson v)) |> Map.ofArray
                             |JBool   boo -> boo 
                             |JNull       -> None
```

Essentially I want to be able to turn a Json object into F# datastructures. (For some background I'm writing a toy json parser that converts text -> Json object -> F# datastructures in separate steps)

Comment: This has been asked a whole bunch of times and it isn't really possible.  The simple reason is suppose you do `let x = parseJson whatever` what is the type of `x` - should the line `x+1` compile? etc

Comment: @JohnPalmer Isnt this what a type provider is for? My take is that the question is not correct, but the answer is create a "type provider"... For gnicholas: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh361034.aspx or check out this: http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/JsonProvider.html and possibly the source for it at https://github.com/fsharp/FSharp.Data/tree/master/src/Json

Comment: @HelgeReneUrholm Note that a type provider actually returns a type which is complex.  It actually needs a template file, so that it can generate the types at compile time.  If you use a new file at run time it needs to have the same format as the template

Comment: F# is [strongly typed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_and_weak_typing). While you can hack your way around this, you should only do that where the language's typing isn't powerful enough. You seem to have a small number of cases, so a discriminated union should work great.

Comment: @JohnPalmer good point regarding template vs runtime. I assumed that was what he wanted. Might be just me and being accustomed to type providers ;-) But then again, I will insist on original question being wrong, and that the answer is still type provider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not a good idea, in your case you pretty much want to return an union at this point. Think about how a function like that would be used, you couldn't pattern match.

For a function like that to work, you could cast every single value to obj with [`box`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340516.aspx), but you would be trapped into casting every time you would need to use your parseJson function  It would work, but it would not be good.

I'm talking about something like this: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2994300/1485641

Comment: That is what I figured. But worth an ask. Thanks!