# How to do the equivalent of pattern matching on native .NET types?

Tags: f#, quotations

```
let print_type_c (x: Type)= 
    if x = typeof<Int32> then "int"
    elif x = typeof<Single> then "float"
    elif x = typeof<Tuple<_>> then "tuple"
    elif x = typeof<FSharpFunc<Tuple<'inp>,'out>> then "function..."
    else failwithf "Not supported(%A)" x

print_type_c (typeof<int>) // prints int
print_type_c (typeof<float32>) // prints float
print_type_c (typeof<int*int>) // throw an exception
```

I am trying to build a primitive F# quotations to Cuda compiler and I need to figure out how to translate tuple types to C struct types in function declarations, but I am really not familiar with how the .NET machinery works. It is disappointing that F# quotations do not return you a nice AST based on discriminated unions which would make everything explicit, but unless I want to do the typechecking myself, I'll have work with this.

What I am asking is - is there a way to the crappy piece of code above with pattern matching on .NET `Type`s, because the above is clearly not working.

Edit: The question is not a duplicate because that linked question is asking how to print the properties of F# records, while I am asking how to print the types of native .NET types (including functions) inside F# quotations. A visual scan of the accepted answer here and there should show that they are completely different and not even using the same functions.

Comment: [Is the syntax used here what you're looking for](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2992139/f-pattern-matching-with-types) ?

Comment: How is it "not working"?

Comment: @asibahi No, I do not think so. See my comment to Fyodor in his answer. I want to avoid using `typeof` for type checking.

Comment: @MarkoGrdinic I don't think you can check what the type for an object is at compile time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Runtime type inference? On types not known at compile time? No, sorry, doesn't exist, you'll have to build one yourself.

To check if a particular type is an instance of a specific generic type, you need to see if it's generic in the first place, and then get its generic definition, and compare that:

```
if x.IsGenericType && (x.GetGenericTypeDefinition() = typeof<System.Tuple<_>>.GetGenericTypeDefinition()) then "tuple" else "not"
```

Note that there is not just one `Tuple` type, but many - `Tuple<_>`, `Tuple<_,_>`, `Tuple<_,_,_>`, and so on - up to 8.

Same goes for `FSharpFunc`:

```
if x.IsGenericType && (x.GetGenericTypeDefinition() = typeof<FSharpFunc<_,_>>.GetGenericTypeDefinition()) then "function" else "not"
```

To get generic arguments of a type, use `.GetGenericArguments()`:

```
if x.IsGenericType && (x.GetGenericTypeDefinition() = typeof<FSharpFunc<_,_>>.GetGenericTypeDefinition()) 
then 
    sprintf "function %s -> %s" (x.GetGenericArguments().[0].Name) (x.GetGenericArguments().[1].Name)
else 
    "not function"
```

Comment: I haven't explained myself well enough. Yeah, it is true that I am doing runtime type inference above, but what I really want to do is specifically avoid that. In a piece of type F# code quotation, all the types are in fact known at compile time. So how do I get them, so I can print them out in C language style for variable declarations? I'd very much rather avoid doing every single combination of Tuple for every single type if I could help it.

Comment: "Printing out in C style" happens at runtime. Therefore, the types being printed need to be represented at runtime.

Comment: Ok...I almost did not even want to test it, but your answer does in fact give me all that I asked for. Thanks.